# DSLR buying guide

Tags: lens, nikon, dslr, nikon-d5300

I am going to buy a DSLR Nikon D5300, please suggest with which kit lens should I go, with D-ZOOM KIT: AF-P DX NIKKOR 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR + AF-P DX NIKKOR 70-300mm f/4.5-6.3G ED VR or with AF-S 18-140mm VR Kit Lens. I am a beginner.

Comment: Although it's Canon instead of Nikon, the principle is the same and holds true here. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38741/why-prefer-the-18-55mm-and-55-250mm-lenses-vs-18-200mm/38744#38744

Comment: Welcome to Photo.SE. Purchase recommendation questions are off topic here, mainly because they're too specific to the individual asking, and they quickly become outdated. But we can help you with questions that would help you make a decision for yourself. For example, if you need help understanding the difference between two similar items, that'd be a fine question.

Comment: Or which choice would be a better fit for the way you want to use your camera.

Comment: Kit lenses are basically disposable. Skip them and get a body so that you can get a set of good lenses (no need to buy them all up front, buy one then add as you need and budget becomes available. Also, if you are already buying a D5300, then you don't need a DSLR Buying Guide, you need a [Lens Buying Guide](http://www.neocamera.com/guide_lens_basics.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nikon D5300 is a great choice as an entry level camera, you may also want to consider a canon T5/T3 which are both cheaper to get familiar with photography.
Enough of the Canon talk haha.

I would recommend the 18-140 (http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-s-dx-nikkor-18-140mm-f%252f3.5-5.6g-ed-vr.html) simply because it is a much better investment than having those other two lens. I personally never use my 18-55 and my 70-300 canon lens. instead I use a 18-200 canon lens for all of my shots.

Comment: Please don't link to your instagram account on every answer here - you can put that on your user profile if you want, but it will be deleted from answers.