# Camera Lens Suggestion for D7200

Tags: lens, camera

I'm planning to buy a new camera along with lens. I have 2 options

1. **Nikon AF-P DX Nikkor 18-55mm** F3.5-5.6G VR and **Nikon AF-P DX Nikkor 70-300mm F4.5-6.3G**
2. **Nikon AF-S DX Nikkor 18-140mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR**

Which option would be better??

Camera- Canon D7200, Usage - Personal photography.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @walther - I've tried to push an answer along more generic lines, which might make it a better fit.

Comment: @Tetsujin, your answer is fine, I just don't think we should encourage more questions like this. Recommendations are short-lived and when it comes to general buying guidelines, I think those can be easily found on the Internet without having this site plagued by countless "I have camera xyz, what lens to buy?".

Comment: Different lenses but the same issue: One lens that covers a very wide focal length range or two lenses that cover less range each. [Why prefer the 18-55mm and 55-250mm lenses vs 18-200mm?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38741/15871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably a Nikon D7200.
Shopping recommendations are off-topic on stack exchange generally - however, I would think about what you need them **for**.

If you don't know yet, then neither of those choices will really let you find out.

Your first choice will leave a big hole in the middle - the exact same trap I fell into when I first started, & I always needed something from the 'hole' whatever I was doing.

The 2nd - personally I think is too short for a 'beginner's walkabout lens'.
I'd look at one of the the 18-300s. They're not fast or particularly sharp, but really not bad at all & at least would let you learn what lengths you use most without too much initial outlay. Consider it a good start-point from which you can work out what you might need in a couple of years.

If your wallet would stretch further, I'd add a good fast 35 or 50mm prime to that, so you can see what a fast, wide aperture can do. Fast zooms cost a fortune, fast primes are relatively cheap.