# Is it sensible to not opt for the kit lens and instead go with Tamron 18-200mm DiII VC Zoom Lens?

Tags: canon, nikon, kit-lens, tamron

I'm thinking of going with a Canon EOS 200D body or Nikon D5600 as my first DSLR and saving 40-50 bucks by not opting for the kit lens and putting the money on Tamron 18-200mm DiII VC Zoom Lens. My aim is to learn basic photography while using the lens for travelling as well as being able to get closer to my subjects.

However, I've read a lot of mixed reviews about 18-200mm Tamron lens and I'm wondering if it's a stupid decision to opt out of the standard kit lens (Canon EF-S 18-55 mm 1: 4.0 – 5.6 IS STM or the Nikon AF-P DFX 18-55 VR). The more reviews I read the more confusing it gets. At the end of the day, I don't want to upgrade just after a few months. I considered checking the 18-135mm kit lens but that's going a bit over my budget. To summarize, should a stick with the kit lens for the time being or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the kit lens. For only $40-50 more than the body only it is a no brainer. Even if you never use it you should be able to sell the kit lens for twice the $40-50 extra you paid.

Beyond that, for why you are better off with something like an 18-55mm kit lens and a 55-250mm cheap telephoto than a single 18-200mm "all-in-one", please see: [Why prefer the 18-55mm and 55-250mm lenses vs 18-200mm?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38741/15871)

A lens like the 18-200mm f/3.5-6.3 is a compromise in versatility vs image quality. You'll probably find that you'll outgrow it sooner than an 18-55mm and 55-250mm combo that can be had for about the same price.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I was going through that very link before posting and I thought the newer version of 18-200mm from Tamron is maybe an improvement over the predecessors? Before reading your answer on the other link I was pretty much convinced to go with it instead of the kit lens. However, I also didn't know about the resale value of the kit lenses. One more point though, the cheap zoom lenses Canon is offering with Rebel series doesn't come with IS.

Comment: If you are talking about the EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III avoid kits with that lens. It's a dog. You can find sellers that sell the Rebels with an 18-55 and 55-250 combo. Any of the various versions of the 55-250 are a lot better than the 75-300mm III (or its direct predecessors).

Comment: There's no newer version of the Tamron 18-200mm f3.5-6.3 DI II VC that was introduced in 2015. All of Tamron's APS-C only lenses are called "Di II". Di (without a 'II' after the 'Di') lenses are for full frame or APS-C cameras.