# How can I fix my Nikon D7000's back focusing problem?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, back-focus

After using a new Nikon D7000 camera for awhile, I've found that that my camera has back- focusing issues - many images are out of focus, even portraits or focusing on near objects where I have focused carefully.

I use 24-70 f/2.8 and 50 f/1.4 lenses and have tried with the center focus point too.

Is there any way I can adjust/tune the focus by setting or firmware?

Comment: Check p. 246 of the manual. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Nikon D7000 is capable of *AF Fine Tune*. For how to determine if your problem is *AF Fine Tune* related see [Do the issues with sharpness I am seeing require AF fine-tuning?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35453/15871)

For how to adjust *AF Fine Tune*, see the following:
[What is the best way to micro-adjust a camera body to a particular lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1/15871)
[Which offers better results: FoCal or LensAlign Pro?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/24354/15871)

Beyond that, many issues that users identify as front-focus or back-focus issues are actually related to a lack of understanding how their camera's complex focus systems work. Just because a dot in the viewfinder is lit up directly over what you want to focus on doesn't necessarily mean that is the exact spot the camera is focused on. The camera will find the greatest area of contrast within the entire area of sensitivity for a given focus point, which is usually quite a bit larger than the dot or square in the viewfinder.