# Best lens for surf photography from the beach

Tags: lens, canon, sports

I have a cannon EOS 60D with an EF-S 18-200 lens. This lens is not good enough for clear pictures at the extent of its zoom. Which lens 400-600 would offer the best value for money: picture quality, speed and lastly portability? Thanks!!

Comment: What lenses have you researched in that range?

Comment: The [Sigma 200-500 f/2.8 APO EX DG](https://www.amazon.com/Sigma-200-500mm-Ultra-Telephoto-Nikon-Cameras/dp/B0013DAPNU/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8), absolutely hands down. **Amazing** value for the price. Make sure to read the reviews.

Comment: Related: [Pictures start in focus then go out of focus?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/61593/15871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 400-600mm range there really isn't much that can be described as "... best value for the money."

You either pay for the best ([Canon EF 400mm f/2.8 L IS II](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/732109-USA/Canon_4412B002_EF_400mm_f_2_8L_IS.html) or [EF 600mm f/4 L IS II](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004M8SWBA)) or you settle for value (any of the [Tamron](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HR6IPSE) or Sigma [Contemporary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00THOYRN6) or [Sports](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1082152-REG/sigma_150_600mm_f_5_6_3_dg_os.html) 150-600mm f/5-6.3 offerings, or the [EF 100-400mm f/5-6.3 L IS II](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PF39PEY)). The [Sigma 120-300mm f/2.8](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/909812-REG/Sigma_137101_120_300mm_f_2_8_DG_OS.html) is somewhere in between (On your APS-C 60D it gives a FoV equivalent of 190-480mm on a FF camera). The [EF 400mm f/5.6 L](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009USW3) that has been around since the early 1990s is another low end option.

None of the above are what might be considered *portable*. The 400/2.8 is the fastest and has the best picture quality.