# What lens/lenses should I get to go with my first DSLR?

Tags: lens, canon, dslr

I've wanted to buy a DSLR camera for quite some time and am finally about to make the buy. Planning on getting a Canon 760D (T6s) but looking for advice one what lens/lenses to get? I don't want to spend a whole lot right now as I am testing the waters, but know I am primarily interested in landscape photography (obviously want to be able to do other things as well though, starting out).

Here are some that I have been seriously considering; not wanting to buy all of these right now, preferably one or two to start, maybe a third once I get into it a bit more.

- EF 50mm f/1.8 STM
- EF-S 24mm f/2.8 STM
- EF-S 10-18mm F4.5-5.6 IS STM
- Sigma 17-50mm f/2.8
- EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS

Or if there are any other recommendations you may have, please let me know!!! Thanks!

Comment: See: [How to choose a lens for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1436); [Lens upgrade paths (sub $1000) for the EF-S 18-55mm IS kit lens for Canon APS-C cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8518) and [this guide on buying lenses](http://www.digital-slr-guide.com/best-digital-slr-lens.html).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the community, Brooks!

For future references, buying advice is frowned upon here, to say the least! Due to the fact that they're more than often primarily opinion based, and there are a lot of other sites around for exactly that.

I've owned several of these lenses that you line up, so I want to give you my personal opinion.

- The 50mm is a great lens, but it's way too narrow for landscapes (my opinion of course). It makes people look just great, and if you're into photographing portraits, it's splendid. But remember, 50mm on a cropped camera will make you back up a bit more often than not.
- The 10-18mm, sure it might be a lot of fun, but it's really wide and you will probably feel "out-of-range" more often than not. It's however terrific when shooting targets such as buildings.
- EF-S 18-55mm and the 17-50mm are good normal zooms, especially the Sigma one, since it has a constant aperture of 2.8. However, using a zoom as your first lens might be fun and easy, but it won't challenge you as much to become a better photographer as much as a prime might (this is still my personal opinion, some people will argue against this, and they might be right).
- The 24mm, as you might expect, is one of my all time favorites, and I used it every day on my cropped camera. The focal range is really good for "all-around-photography". It covers photographing people pretty well, it's fun for landscapes and it makes you move to get to the right point where you want to shoot instead of just zooming in. It's also dirt cheap and light and easy!

You will probably be happy with whichever one you choose, but now you have my two cents about it! Go 24mm Go!

Comment: Tindra, I do not agree with you about 10-18mm. I use FF camera and 16-35 and find it very versatile for landscape. Of course this focal length add a lot of challenges, but at the end this is the way to become better photograph :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov It's probably great for landscapes, I meant "out-of-range" in more daily use, like photographing friends! You gotta get pretty close at some points! But absolutely, I use my 17-40mm on a FF pretty much daily and I love it! I just felt like, due to the competing primes in his list for the "First lens", it falls behind. But my opinion does not have to be the correct one! :)

Comment: This is one of the better ways to answer an off topic question, but not answering it is still better. It's more useful to explain, in comments, how the OP could ask a more on topic question.

Answer (score 0):

Very rightly said by Tindra.

But I opine for the EF-S 18-55mm or the 17-50mm lens. The reason being that these lenses will provide you a decent wide angle for landscapes. Also the zoom will let you narrow the angle to get you nearer to the scene. And the Sigma's constant aperture of 2.8 would be handy to get that extra depth in your photos.

I suggest going for anyone of these as you mentioned 'obviously want to be able to do other things as well though, starting out'.

Happy Photographing.

Comment: Extra depth? The lens would have shorter depth of field